# Restrict Jquery and jQuery UI to my Embedded React App

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to include jQuery and jQuery UI in my react app that is embedded in 3rd party websites without polluting the unsuspecting host site with those libraries?

**Update. Comments asked for reasons.**

I need Draggable, resizeable, Rotatable features.  There is a react-resizable-rotatable-draggable library, which is no longer supported and seems hard to style. I'm converting an existing app that uses Jquery UI so exploring that option makes sense.

Comment: No. See the many questions pertaining to loading multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: You might ask yourself why you're using _either_ library. jQueryUI has been out of development for half a decade, having been replaced by many more modern tools, and jQuery itself  just isn't very relevant or necessary anymore.

Comment: Because I need draggable, rotateable, resizeable and the react module for that seems abandoned.  Also, i'm converting an app that used jquery ui, so its my first stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to package your code, there should be no issues in terms of "polluting" the global namespace or causing version conflicts with jQuery.

The bundlers provide [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), which should reduce the amount of jQuery code that is added, though how much unused code would be eliminated is anyone's guess, and depends on your usage.

Comment: Great! i'm using webpack as it comes with https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @Will great, you should be all set, then!

Comment: thanks,  but I have follow up question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338190/how-to-import-jquery-ui-into-a-react-compoent

Comment: @Will looks like you figured it out already!

Comment: Unfortunatly, it seems like our code is polluting the site version of jQuery.  Results in errors like TypeError: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function. Any ideas why or how to debug? @Codebling ?

Comment: @Will maybe you can post a new question with details and link it?

Comment: It seems like you've already decided that your code is polluting the global namespace, but is it possible that this is not the case? You'll have to provide more details about what is "your code" and what is "site code" for anyone to be able to look into this further, I think

Comment: When I include the widget, the jQuery version changes from 1.1 to 3.x   - It is very clear its polluting the site code with the widget's version of jQuery

Comment: @Will how are you including the widget in the site? I think it makes sense for you to post a new question, there will likely be too many details to follow in comments

Comment: Ill do that today.  I'm just adding it as a script and a css tag